# Opening firewall of ubuntu server to access gunicorn/Flask app running on port 80

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw, gunicorn

I am trying to serve an intranet application from a server running Ubuntu 18.04 on our local network

The application is written in `Flask` and I have deployed it using `gunicorn` with the command

```
me@appserver:~$ authbind gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:80 app:app
```

SSHing into the server with display port forwarding I can open up the app using firefox and interact with it just fine. However when I try from another machine on the subnet the connection is refused.

I can telnet into port 22 okay, i.e.

```
me@clientmachine:~$ telnet 123.45.67.89 22
Trying 123.45.67.89...
Connected to 123.45.67.89.
```

but I get a connection refused on port 80

```
me@clientmachine:~$ telnet 123.45.67.89 80
Trying 123.45.67.89...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I have configured the the firewall using `ufw` with command

```
me@appserver:~$ sudo ufw allow 80
```

which gives me

```
me@appserver:~$ sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/udp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/udp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I also confirmed this with

```
me@appserver:~$ netstat -an | grep :80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

me@appserver:~$ lsof -i:80
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn 1818 me    5u  IPv4  31215      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
gunicorn 1822 me    5u  IPv4  31215      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
gunicorn 1823 me    5u  IPv4  31215      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
gunicorn 1824 me    5u  IPv4  31215      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
gunicorn 1825 me    5u  IPv4  31215      0t0  TCP localhost:http (LISTEN)
```

and

```
me@appserver:~$ sudo iptables -L -n | grep :80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
```

However, running `nmap` from the client shows 80 but says that is closed

```
me@clientmachine:~$ nmap 123.45.67.89

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-24 16:41 AEST
Nmap scan report for appserver.myuni.edu (123.45.67.89)
Host is up (0.00041s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
```

Any idea why this would be and how to fix it? Can this sort of thing be managed by settings on the subnet that are managed by the network administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `Connection refused` suggests that nothing is listening on that port, the port is closed. If the firewall would be preventing the access you would receive a message about a timeout.

The problem is that you started your application to listen only on the loopback interface `127.0.0.1`. So it is only available on that interface, which your `netstat` output confirms. If you want to make it available on the external interface you have to provide that IP on startup, or `0.0.0.0` to allow all interfaces.

```
me@appserver:~$ authbind gunicorn -w 4 -b 123.45.67.89:80 app:app
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: authbind does not work out of the box, for the configuration you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802211/5687711